# how to display image in td after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to display the image in the particular td after ajax success but it not displaying the image it not working anyone guide me were i went wrong below is my code

ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.edit1').on('change', function() {
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
            var clientid = document.getElementById("client").value;
            account_id = document.getElementById("account_id").value;
            $(this).parent().next().find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "clientnetworkpricelist/routestatusupdate.php",
                data: "value=" + $(this).val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1] + "&clientid=" + clientid + "&account_id=" + account_id,
                success: function(result) {
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(result); //added line
                    var obj = data;
                    $('#CPH_GridView1_Status' + arr[2]).empty();
                    $('#CPH_GridView1_Status' + arr[2]).append(data.status);
                    $('.ajax').html($(this).val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

routestatusupdate.php

```
{

/** 
some function for display the result

**/

$result=array();
$result['status']='<img  src="image/' . $status . 'f.png" />';
$result['seleniumrouteupdate']=$seleniumrouteupdaterow;
$result['routeupdate']=$routeupdate;
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

my routestatusupdate.php out put looks like

```
{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Decreasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line as data is already in JSON format:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(result); //added line
```

By removing this you also need to update your var like this :

```
var obj = result;
```

Second thing, your JSON is in wrong format.. it should be output like this :

```
[{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"},{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Decreasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}]
```

You probably have that echo json_encode($result); in two places, you need to combine them in one response array and echo json_encode($results);

Here is example of how you can do this (PHP):

```
function something($status, $seleniumrouteupdaterow,$routeupdate) {
   $result=array();
   $result['status']='<img  src="image/' . $status . 'f.png" />';
   $result['seleniumrouteupdate']=$seleniumrouteupdaterow;
   $result['routeupdate']=$routeupdate;
   return $result;
}

// ....PHP code
$json = array();
$json[] = something($status, $seleniumrouteupdaterow,$routeupdate);
// ... some other code
$json[] = something($status, $seleniumrouteupdaterow,$routeupdate);
echo json_encode($json);
```

And at end you need also to update this line:

```
$('#CPH_GridView1_Status' + arr[2]).append(data.status);
```

Since data.status is an array you need to target the right element (first or second):

```
$('#CPH_GridView1_Status' + arr[2]).append(data.status[0]);
```

That would append your first status message..

Comment: it showing error :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: As I was saying, result is already in JSON format .. there is no need to parse it so this line should be removed

Comment: i removed it showing error:ReferenceError: data is not defined
 

(24 out of range 2)

Comment: can you guide me how to make output look like this :[{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"},{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Decreasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}]

Comment: I've updated the answer and added a PHP example (also look at the beginning how to update your javascript variable)